# How to remove data in a JSON array?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have this data:

```
{"items":[{"Code":"S-B-03","Quantity":"3pcs.","Desc":"Ballpen Black","Ucost":4.75},{"Code":"S-B-34","Quantity":"2pcs.","Desc":"Ballpen Black","Ucost":8.75}]}
```

I would like to remove the first data. I can access the first data using `object.items[0]`. I want to remove the first data.

I tried:

```
object.items[0].remove("Code");
object.items[0].remove("Quantity");
object.items[0].remove("Desc");
object.items[0].remove("Ucost");
```

But it is not working.

Comment: object.items.remove("Ucost"); Remove all object of json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) to replace the array. For example:

```
object.items = object.items.slice(1);
```

You can also use [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) which changes the contents of the array in place. For example:

```
object.items.splice(0, 1);
```

This deletes the first item from the array.

Answer (score 2):

Remove like this.

`object.items.splice(0,1)`

Since `items` is an array we can simply use `Array.splice` to remove the element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) operator:

```
// Remove the property "Code" from object.items[0]
delete object.items[0]["Code"];

// Remove the item with index 0 from object.items:
delete object.items[0];
```

Comment: This will left `undefined` or `null` in the array. Have you tried it before posting?

Comment: @Braj I know that this doesn't rearrange the indices inside the array, I was more thinking about the *remove property from object* use case and added the second example for completion. Granted, I misinterpreted the OP's intent, tiredness, the `object.items[0].remove("Code");` bits and vague terminology threw me off :) The perfect answer would be a combination of the two methods depending on what is removed.

Answer (score 0):

We can remove the json data, using below step

object.items.splice(0,1)

because item is an array, we can easily remove json data using array.splice() method